# How to send message from broker to all clients using MQTT in .NET Framework?

Tags: c#, client, mqtt, broker

I am trying to make an application where I need the broker to send messages to (all) clients and also the cleints send message to the broker. The part where I send message to the broker, it is working fine, but I couldn't figure out how to send message from the broker to (all) clients.

This is my broker:

```
private static int MessageCounter = 0;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateLogger();

            MqttServerOptionsBuilder options = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder()
                .WithDefaultEndpoint()
                .WithDefaultEndpointPort(707)
                .WithConnectionValidator(OnNewConnection)
                .WithApplicationMessageInterceptor(OnNewMessage);


            IMqttServer mqttServer = new MqttFactory().CreateMqttServer();

            mqttServer.StartAsync(options.Build()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public static void OnNewConnection(MqttConnectionValidatorContext context)
        {
            Log.Logger.Information(
                    "New connection: ClientId = {clientId}, Endpoint = {endpoint}, CleanSession = {cleanSession}",
                    context.ClientId,
                    context.Endpoint,
                    context.CleanSession);
        }

        public static void OnNewMessage(MqttApplicationMessageInterceptorContext context)
        {
            var payload = context.ApplicationMessage?.Payload == null ? null : Encoding.UTF8.GetString(context.ApplicationMessage?.Payload);

          
            Log.Logger.Information(
                "MessageId: {MessageCounter} - TimeStamp: {TimeStamp} -- Message: ClientId = {clientId}, Topic = {topic}, Payload = {payload}, QoS = {qos}, Retain-Flag = {retainFlag}",
                MessageCounter,
                DateTime.Now,
                context.ClientId,
                context.ApplicationMessage?.Topic,
                payload,
                context.ApplicationMessage?.QualityOfServiceLevel,
                context.ApplicationMessage?.Retain);
        }

    }
```

And this is my client:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .MinimumLevel.Debug()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console()
                .CreateLogger();

            MqttClientOptionsBuilder builder = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                                        .WithClientId("Dev.To")
                                        .WithTcpServer("localhost", 707);

            ManagedMqttClientOptions options = new ManagedMqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                                    .WithAutoReconnectDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
                                    .WithClientOptions(builder.Build())
                                    .Build();

            IManagedMqttClient _mqttClient = new MqttFactory().CreateManagedMqttClient();

            _mqttClient.ConnectedHandler = new MqttClientConnectedHandlerDelegate(OnConnected);
            _mqttClient.DisconnectedHandler = new MqttClientDisconnectedHandlerDelegate(OnDisconnected);
            _mqttClient.ConnectingFailedHandler = new ConnectingFailedHandlerDelegate(OnConnectingFailed);

            _mqttClient.ApplicationMessageReceivedHandler = new MqttApplicationMessageReceivedHandlerDelegate(a =>
            {
                Log.Logger.Information("Message recieved: {payload}", a.ApplicationMessage);
            });

            _mqttClient.StartAsync(options).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            //Try this maybeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee
            MqttClientSubscribeOptions _subscribeOptions = new MqttClientSubscribeOptions();
            
            while (true)
            {
                string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { message = Console.ReadLine(), sent= DateTimeOffset.UtcNow });
                _mqttClient.PublishAsync("topic", json);
                Task.Delay(100).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
            }
        }

        public static void OnConnected(MqttClientConnectedEventArgs obj)
        {
            Log.Logger.Information("Successfully connected.");
        }

        public static void OnConnectingFailed(ManagedProcessFailedEventArgs obj)
        {
            Log.Logger.Warning("Couldn't connect to broker.");
        }

        public static void OnDisconnected(MqttClientDisconnectedEventArgs obj)
        {
            Log.Logger.Information("Successfully disconnected.");
        }
    }
```

I read about something "subscribe", also tried to subscribe a topic, but it's not working for me. I also tried the MqttFactory.

Comment: You may need to rethink your model here, the broker should only be sending messages to clients that match topic patterns that the clients have already subscribed to. You should not be sending arbitrary messages as you do not know what code the clients have to handle messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out! I am going to answer it, maybe it will be useful later, for someone! :)

1. Edit the Main classes to:

   static async Task Main(string[] args)
2. Add a UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler to the Client, and subscribe to a topic:

   ```
            _mqttClient.UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler(e =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received message: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload));
            if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload).Contains("message to all clients"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("We are going to do send this message");
            }
        });
        await _mqttClient.SubscribeAsync("test/topic");
   ```
3. Add MqttApplicationMessageBuilder and PublishAsync to the Broker:

   ```
            mqttServer.StartAsync(options.Build()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        var message = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
            .WithTopic("test/topic")
            .WithPayload("Hello, World!")
            .Build();

        await mqttServer.PublishAsync(message);

        Console.WriteLine("Message sent.");
   ```

So the full code is like this:

Broker:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {

        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

        MqttServerOptionsBuilder options = new MqttServerOptionsBuilder()
            .WithDefaultEndpoint()
            .WithDefaultEndpointPort(707)
            .WithConnectionValidator(OnNewConnection)
            .WithApplicationMessageInterceptor(OnNewMessage);


        IMqttServer mqttServer = new MqttFactory().CreateMqttServer();

        mqttServer.StartAsync(options.Build()).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        var message = new MqttApplicationMessageBuilder()
            .WithTopic("test/topic")
            .WithPayload("Hello, World!")
            .Build();

        await mqttServer.PublishAsync(message);

        Console.WriteLine("Message sent.");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static void OnNewConnection(MqttConnectionValidatorContext context)
    {
        Log.Logger.Information(
                "New connection: ClientId = {clientId}, Endpoint = {endpoint}, CleanSession = {cleanSession}",
                context.ClientId,
                context.Endpoint,
                context.CleanSession);
    }

    public static void OnNewMessage(MqttApplicationMessageInterceptorContext context)
    {
        var payload = context.ApplicationMessage?.Payload == null ? null : Encoding.UTF8.GetString(context.ApplicationMessage?.Payload);

        Log.Logger.Information(
            "MessageId: {MessageCounter} - TimeStamp: {TimeStamp} -- Message: ClientId = {clientId}, Topic = {topic}, Payload = {payload}, QoS = {qos}, Retain-Flag = {retainFlag}",
            MessageCounter,
            DateTime.Now,
            context.ClientId,
            context.ApplicationMessage?.Topic,
            payload,
            context.ApplicationMessage?.QualityOfServiceLevel,
            context.ApplicationMessage?.Retain);


        if (payload.Contains("refresh"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("refresh boys!");
        }
        if (payload.Contains("update"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Update boys!");
        }

    }
```

Client:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console()
            .CreateLogger();

        MqttClientOptionsBuilder builder = new MqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                                    .WithClientId("Dev.Four")
                                    .WithTcpServer("localhost", 707);

        ManagedMqttClientOptions options = new ManagedMqttClientOptionsBuilder()
                                .WithAutoReconnectDelay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60))
                                .WithClientOptions(builder.Build())
                                .Build();

        IManagedMqttClient _mqttClient = new MqttFactory().CreateManagedMqttClient();

        _mqttClient.ConnectedHandler = new MqttClientConnectedHandlerDelegate(OnConnected);
        _mqttClient.DisconnectedHandler = new MqttClientDisconnectedHandlerDelegate(OnDisconnected);
        _mqttClient.ConnectingFailedHandler = new ConnectingFailedHandlerDelegate(OnConnectingFailed);

        _mqttClient.ApplicationMessageReceivedHandler = new MqttApplicationMessageReceivedHandlerDelegate(a =>
        {
            Log.Logger.Information("Message recieved: {payload}", a.ApplicationMessage);
        });

        _mqttClient.StartAsync(options).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        _mqttClient.UseApplicationMessageReceivedHandler(e =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Received message: " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload));
            if (Encoding.UTF8.GetString(e.ApplicationMessage.Payload).Contains("message to all clients"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("We are going to do send this message");
            }
        });
        await _mqttClient.SubscribeAsync("test/topic");

        while (true)
        {
            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new { message = Console.ReadLine(), sent = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow });
            _mqttClient.PublishAsync("test/topic", json);

            Task.Delay(0).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }

    public static void OnConnected(MqttClientConnectedEventArgs obj)
    {
        Log.Logger.Information("Successfully connected.");
    }

    public static void OnConnectingFailed(ManagedProcessFailedEventArgs obj)
    {
        Log.Logger.Warning("Couldn't connect to broker.");
    }

    public static void OnDisconnected(MqttClientDisconnectedEventArgs obj)
    {
        Log.Logger.Information("Successfully disconnected.");
    }
```

So now it's working like this:
[This is how it's works, and this is what I wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSMRG.png)